# CUDA 9.1 Post-installation Actions

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the CUDA .deb package from the official website. It seems to have installed successfully.

Now I need to perform the mandatory post-installation actions from the [manual](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.1/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf).

1. Should the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables be changed in .bashrc?
2. It wants me to create a file in /usr/lib/systemd/system/, but my Ubuntu does not have the system subaddressary. Should I simply create it?

   ```
   $ ls -la /usr/lib/systemd
   total 28
   drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 .
   drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 4096 Dec 13 12:31 ..
   drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 boot
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug  1 13:18 catalog
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 network
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug  1 13:22 user
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug  1 13:18 user-generators

   $ cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
   bash: cd: /usr/lib/systemd/system: No such file or directory
   ```

Comment: This `/usr/lib/systemd/system` exists please check carefully!

Comment: Thank you, but it is NOT there. However, I have `/lib/systemd/system`

Comment: ok do you have `/usr/lib/systemd`

Comment: You will need to create `system` location in `/usr/lib/systemd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following, add these to the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

64 bit only -

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

32 bit only-

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Then for that file do: `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system && sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service`, and add:

```
[Unit]
Description=NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nvidia-persistenced/nvidia-persistenced.pid
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then set it up:

```
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-persistenced
```

Then following that manual to avoid issues with hotadds comment out this line:

```
# Memory hotadd request
SUBSYSTEM=="memory", ACTION=="add", DEVPATH=="/devices/system/memory/memory[0-9]*", TEST=="state", ATTR{state}="online"
```

in the `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules` file by adding a `#` to that line.

Reload:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```